# A result about quadratic numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, modular-arithmetic

I'm stuck in the middle of an exercise about quadratic numbers. Let me quickly sum it up.

**Let $d$ be a positive integer that is not the square of any integer.**

1. Let $n \in \mathbb N^*.$ Prove the existence of $(p_n,q_n) \in \mathbb Z^2 $such that $$ 0<q_n \leq n \; \text {and} \; |p_n-q_n \sqrt {d}|<\frac{1}{n} $$
2. Show that the sequence $((p_n,q_n))_{n \in \mathbb N^{*}} $ takes infinitely many different values.
3. Show that $$ |p_n^{2}-d q_n ^{2}| \leq 2 \sqrt d+1$$
4. Prove the existence of $(a,b)$ , $(a',b') \in \mathbb Z \times\mathbb N^*$ and $A \in \mathbb Z^*$ such that $$\left\{
       \begin{array}{ll}
          (a,b) \neq (a',b') \\
           a^2-db^2=a'^2-db'^2= A \\
           a \equiv a' \; mod \; |A|  \\
           b \equiv b' \; mod \; |A|
       \end{array}
   \right.$$

I completed 1,2,3 and I'm stuck on 4, although I know how it should be dealt with.

It's all about pigeonhole principle : take all pairs $(p_n,q_n)$ as pigeons (they are infinitely many by 2.)  and the values of $ |p_n^{2}-d q_n ^{2}|$ as holes. The holes range from $1$ to $floor(2 \sqrt d+1)$ according to 3.

Therefore, there must a be an infinite subsequence $(p_{\phi(n)},q_{\phi(n)})$, and some $K \in \mathbb Z^*$ such that $$ \forall n, |p_{\phi(n)}^{2}-d q_{\phi(n)} ^{2}|=K $$

By the same pigeonhole argument, there exists an infinite subsequence $(p_{\phi(\psi(n))},q_{\phi(\psi(n))})$ and some $K'$ (actually $K=K'$ or $K'=-K$) such that $$ \forall n, p_{\phi(\psi(n))}^{2}-d q_{\phi(\psi(n))} ^{2}=K' $$

**Now I need to get the modulo condition on $p_{\phi(\psi(n))}$ and $q_{\phi(\psi(n))}$**

Pigeonhole principle again!, you may say. Well it doesn't work out very well.

One may want to consider the modulo $|K'|$ classes as holes and $p_{\phi(\psi(n))}$ and $q_{\phi(\psi(n))}$ as pigeons.

**The issue is that ,as this point, nothing is known on $p_{\phi(\psi(n))}$and $q_{\phi(\psi(n))}$  (except that the pair $(p_{\phi(\psi(n))},q_{\phi(\psi(n))})$takes infinitely many different values).** Therefore, one of the two sequences has to take infinitely many different values. But what about the other sequence ?

**Say WLOG, $p_n$ takes infinitely many different values and $q_n$ doesn't. Then I cannot apply the infinite version of the pigeonhole principle to $q_n$**

Nevertheless, one can easily show that, since $\sqrt d$ is irrational, $$q_n \rightarrow \infty \; \text{and} \;  p_n \text{is not bounded} $$

Does this help ?

This is where I'm stuck. I hope you'll take the time to read through all this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? Some of this is standard continued fractions in appearance, but...

Comment: it's part of a much bigger problem about diophantine equations.

Comment: What does the extra subscript $n$ in part (2) mean?

Comment: it means that the sequence considered is a sequence of pairs namely the sequence $(p_n,q_n)$

Comment: best to leave it out: you currently have $((p_n,q_n))_n$ which makes no sense.

Comment: it should make sense now... since you're familiar with diophantine equations, do you know a way to obviate using pigeonhole principle again and again ?

Comment: Put it this way: part 1 is nonstandard; how about if you tell me how you did that; then what is the larger problem of which this is a part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first mistake is that the holes to begin part 4 should be 
$$ - \lfloor 1 + 2 \sqrt d \rfloor \leq A \leq \lfloor 1 + 2 \sqrt d \rfloor. $$
It does not matter that $0$ is impossible.

Do not keep typing subsequences with extra symbols. It confuses everything. Or just change letters from $p,q$ to something else. I wouldn't usually bother, but this once I will switch to capital letters.

Now, we have an infinite (sub)sequence, using letter $j,$ with
$$ P_j^2 - d Q_j^2 = A.  $$

The equivalence classes $\pmod {|A|}$ have standard representatives $0,1,2,\ldots, |A|-1,$ numbering exactly $|A|.$ So the pigeons $(P_j,Q_j)$  are being placed into $A^2$ holes, the first coordinate ($P_j$) from $0$ to $|A|-1,$ the second coordinate  ($Q_j$) also from $0$ to $|A|-1.$

Comment: I think it's right ! I didn't occur to me that the holes could form a grid. Thanks !